# Error to show the image inside the table! Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

I am getting the url of the image and passing to transform and image and be 
    created inside the cell of the table, however this returning me error saying that it is empty!

Please can someone help me!

Here are my two classes.

```
import UIKit

var margemPadrao : CGFloat = 10.0
var alturaNavBar : CGFloat = 0.0
var alturaStatusBar:CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
var alturaTela : CGFloat = 0.0
var larguraTela : CGFloat = 0.0
var alturaCelula : CGFloat = 0.0


var listaCardNovidades:[Novidades] = []

class NewsScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBAction func menuButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        toggleSideMenuView()
    }


    var minhaTabela:UITableView = UITableView()
    var meuActivityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buscaJSON()
        alturaTela = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        larguraTela = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        alturaNavBar = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!

        //pegando a cor da view para ser igual na tabela
        let corViewbackground:UIColor = self.view.backgroundColor!

        //setando o frame da tabela com altura largura e posicionamentos
        minhaTabela.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: larguraTela, height: alturaTela)

        meuActivityIndicator.frame = minhaTabela.frame

        minhaTabela.delegate = self
        minhaTabela.dataSource = self

        //backgroundo color da tabela
        minhaTabela.backgroundColor = corViewbackground

        //retirando as linhas da tabela
        minhaTabela.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

        minhaTabela.register(CelulaCard.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CelularCard")
        minhaTabela.scrollsToTop = false

        meuActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        meuActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

        self.view.addSubview(minhaTabela)
        minhaTabela.isHidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(meuActivityIndicator)

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  listaCardNovidades.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let celula = minhaTabela.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CelularCard", for: indexPath) as! CelulaCard

        celula.textoTitulo.text = listaCardNovidades[indexPath.row].titulo
        //celula.self.caminhoImagem = listaCardNovidades[indexPath.row].imagem
        celula.self.caminhoImagem = listaCardNovidades[indexPath.row].imagem

        return celula
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return alturaCelula
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        minhaTabela.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }



    /*FUNÇÃO PARA CARREGAR O JSON*/

    func buscaJSON(){
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        let urlApi = "https://www.floratilemevidencia.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/download?filter[pagina]=ultimas-novidades"
        if let url = URL(string: urlApi) {
            session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil{
                    print("The error is: \(error!)")
                    return
                }else if let jsonData = data {
                    do{
                        let parsedJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                        //print(parsedJSON)
                        for json in parsedJSON{
                            guard let dados = json["title"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {return}
                            let n = Novidades()
                            n.titulo = dados["rendered"] as! String
                            n.imagem = json["thumbnail_pdf"] as! String
                            n.arquivo = json["arquivo"] as! String

                            listaCardNovidades.append(n)

                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.minhaTabela.isHidden = false
                            self.minhaTabela.reloadData()
                            self.meuActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        }
//                        for item in listaCardNovidades{
//                            print (item.arquivo)
//                            print (item.imagem)
//                            print (item.titulo)
//                            print ("-------------------------------------------")
//                        }
                    } catch let error as Error{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }

            }).resume()
        }
    }

}







//Second Class



import UIKit


class CelulaCard: UITableViewCell {

    var caminhoImagem:String = ""

    var imagemPdfWebView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var textoTitulo:UILabel = UILabel()


    var fundoCard:UIView = UIView()
    var indicador:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.236424, green: 0.610663 , blue: 0.374416, alpha: 1)

        fundoCard.frame = CGRect(
            x: margemPadrao,
            y: margemPadrao,
            width: larguraTela-2*margemPadrao,
            height: 360
        )

        fundoCard.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        fundoCard.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0


        imagemPdfWebView.frame = CGRect(
            x: fundoCard.frame.minX+margemPadrao,
            y: fundoCard.frame.minY+margemPadrao,
            width: fundoCard.frame.size.width-2*margemPadrao,
            height: fundoCard.frame.size.height-6*margemPadrao
        )

        self.indicador.frame = self.imagemPdfWebView.frame
        indicador.startAnimating()
        indicador.hidesWhenStopped = true

        textoTitulo.frame = CGRect(
            x: imagemPdfWebView.frame.minX,
            y: imagemPdfWebView.frame.maxY+5,
            width: imagemPdfWebView.frame.size.width,
            height: 20
        )

        alturaCelula = fundoCard.frame.size.height+2*margemPadrao+20


        textoTitulo.textAlignment = .center
        textoTitulo.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        textoTitulo.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17)


        imagemPdfWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imagemPdfWebView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imagemPdfWebView.clipsToBounds = true

        //Para mudar a cor de quando é selecionado
        let bgColorView:UIView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

        /*teste*/
        print("AKI ->\(caminhoImagem)")

        self.addSubview(fundoCard)
        self.addSubview(indicador)


        self.addSubview(imagemPdfWebView)
        self.addSubview(textoTitulo)



        carregarImagemUrl(imageUrl: caminhoImagem)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()



        //        let urlImagem : URL = URL(string: caminhoImagem)!
        //        let net:NetworkService = NetworkService(url: urlImagem)
        //
        //        net.downloadImage { (imageData) in
        //            var minhaImg:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
        //            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //                self.imagemPdfWebView.image = minhaImg
        //
        //            }
    }
    func carregarImagemUrl(imageUrl:String){
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in
            if let imageData = responseData{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.imagemPdfWebView.image = UIImage(data : imageData)
                })
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    //        let url = URL(string: self.caminhoImagem)
    //        let data = NSData(contentsOf:url!)
    //
    //        // It is the best way to manage nil issue.
    //        if (data?.length)! > 0 {
    //            self.imagemPdfWebView.image = UIImage(data:data! as Data)
    //        } else {
    //            // In this when data is nil or empty then we can assign a placeholder image
    //            print("Não foi possível ERRO")
    //        }



}
```

Comment: Why don't use SDWebImage or Alamofire to do this?

Comment: How do I implement alamofire in my code?

Comment: Check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/147086/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started-2

Comment: Is this the correct call of this variable from one class to another?  
var caminhoImagem:String = ""

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to register the custom cell correctly.

```
var nibName = UINib(nibName: "CelularCard", bundle:nil)
self.tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CelularCard")
```

Then you need to use image loader library to load the image into image view using url. I recommend to use [KFSwiftImageLoader](https://github.com/kiavashfaisali/KFSwiftImageLoader)

```
let imageURL= listaCardNovidades[indexPath.row].imagem
celula.self.caminhoImagem.loadImage(urlString: imageURL)
```